# running asp.vnext starter project from sources

Tags: asp.net-core

do you know if is available some guide how to run a project created from the sample starter project from sources? I suppose that cloning the repositories from github and configuring the solution may be possible to do this, may be very useful to study how it works.

thanks,

Luca
this is the outuput of the kvm list command
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------                    -----

> ```
>    1.0.0-beta1       CLR     amd64        C:\Users\luca\.kre\packages  
>    1.0.0-beta1       CLR     x86          C:\Users\luca\.kre\packages    
>    1.0.0-beta1       CoreCLR amd64        C:\Users\luca\.kre\packages   
>    1.0.0-beta1       CoreCLR x86          C:\Users\luca\.kre\packages   
>    1.0.0-beta2-10724 CLR     x86          C:\Users\luca\.kre\packages   
>    1.0.0-beta2-10724 CoreCLR x86          C:\Users\luca\.kre\packages   
>    1.0.0-beta2-10726 CLR     x86          C:\Users\luca\.kre\packages   
>    1.0.0-rc1-10781   CLR     x86          C:\Users\luca\.kre\packages   
>    1.0.0-rc1-10781   CoreCLR x86          C:\Users\luca\.kre\packages   
>    1.0.0-rc1-10798   CLR     x86          C:\Users\luca\.kre\packages   
>    1.0.0-rc1-10798   CoreCLR x86          C:\Users\luca\.kre\packages      *    1.0.0-rc1-10804   CLR     x86
> ```
>
> C:\Users\luca.kre\packages default

I cloned and added those repositories:
Configuration,DataCommon,Data Protection,Dependency Injection,Diagnostic,Entity Framework, File System, Hosting, HttpAbstraction,Identity, KRuntime, Logging, Mvc, Razor, Routing, Scaffolding, Security, Static Files, WebSockets Abstractions.
Seems to me those are the needed repositories need to run it from local sources.

other errors:

```
6>D:\Studio\vs2015\FromSource\KRuntimeSrc\Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn\RoslynCompiler.cs(10,25): ASP.NET 5.0 error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'PortableExecutable' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Reflection' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
6>D:\Studio\vs2015\FromSource\KRuntimeSrc\Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn\AssemblyNeutral\EmbeddedReferencesHelper.cs(5,25): ASP.NET 5.0 error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Metadata' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Reflection' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
6>D:\Studio\vs2015\FromSource\KRuntimeSrc\Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn\AssemblyNeutral\EmbeddedReferencesHelper.cs(6,25): ASP.NET 5.0 error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'PortableExecutable' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Reflection' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
6>D:\Studio\vs2015\FromSource\KRuntimeSrc\Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn\AssemblyNeutral\TypeCompilationContext.cs(57,47): ASP.NET 5.0 error CS0012: The type 'ImmutableArray<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.1.33.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
6>D:\Studio\vs2015\FromSource\KRuntimeSrc\Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn\AssemblyNeutral\TypeCompilationContext.cs(57,36): ASP.NET 5.0 error CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.INamedTypeSymbol>' because 'System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.INamedTypeSymbol>' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
6>D:\Studio\vs2015\FromSource\KRuntimeSrc\Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn\AssemblyNeutral\TypeCompilationContext.cs(62,38): ASP.NET 5.0 error CS0012: The type 'ImmutableArray<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.1.33.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Install VS 2015
2. Clone the repos that you want to build
3. If you want to build the dev branch, make sure you install the dev KRE (https://github.com/aspnet/home/tree/dev)
4. Open the solution in VS and build

Comment: tried but I receive a lot of errors of type

The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.EntityServiceCollectionExtensions.AddEntityFramework(Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.IConfiguration)' and 'Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.EntityServiceCollectionExtensions.AddEntityFramework(Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.IConfiguration)

Comment: 1. What is the output of `kvm list`? 2. What project did you clone and what branch?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to include the source of one of the dependencies, you can:

- clone the repo locally with git (eg. git clone http://github.com/aspnet/Mvc for the MVC 6 repository)
- execute `kpm restore` in the repos local folder
- then reference the source in your solution's global.json. Add the `"sources"` attributes as follows:

  ```
  global.json
  {
      "sources": [ "src", "test", "/path/to/your/project/src" ]
  }
  ```

You might also need to tweak the dependencies in your `project.json` for the projects where you want to use the source:

```
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta1"
```

try changing it to

```
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": ""
```

Another thing to try is to use `kpm restore` in your project folder. The K Package Manager should go and get any of the dependencies listed in your project.json file, but in practice, I found that it doesn't always find the specific versions I'm looking for.

Comment: from what I know i have to write "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "" to say it's a local project reference. I have done this with all the repositories, seems that is partially working but I have errors. I tried this way with the Scaffolding repository alone and it's working fine. The problem is the use of all repositories clones

Comment: In `global.json` it's recommended to use forward slashes (`/`) instead of backslashes (which need to be escaped) for two reasons: 1. It's a lot cleaner and easier to read, and 2. It works cross-platform (forward slashes also work in Windows).

Comment: @Eilon Agreed that is much cleaner... I keep forgetting that vNext is no longer windows-centric. Edited as such.